# Xcode splash screen not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, splash-screen

I am currently building an iOS objective c application and am working on the splash screen now but am running into display issues when running on a device.

This is how the layout is set up in my storyboard:

[image]

This is how the screen looks in a simulator, the correct version:

[image]

And this is how it looks on a device, the incorrect version:

[image]

Has anyone ever run into this problem and if so, how did you fix it?  I'd be happy to provide any code if needed but i'm not sure what to include that would help solve the problem.

Comment: So the Simulator one is what you want?

Comment: Yes, the simulator is the correct one

Comment: Simulator is running the same device as real one?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: debug view hierarchy and see if the views are being clipped?

Comment: Or check the image format, simulator accepts more formats than a real device

Comment: Can you please check image all size (All device size with ratina display)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem, too simple, this is an **iOS BUG** that can appear when you build directly from XCode, there's no specific solution, try restarting the iOS Device, I have never seen it when downloading the app from apple store after publishing, so simply ignore it, people who will download the app from apple store will not see this.